# Wildcard subdomains and CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, cakephp-2.3

I'm not strong in .htaccess and for this reason I need your help.
Recently I purchased wildcard SSL certificate and changing http to https doesn't work properly.
The site is build on CakePHP 2.3 and `public_html` directory has a following structure:

```
/app
/lib
/plugins
/Cake
/sub1.domain.com
 - app
 - lib
 - plugins
 - ...
/sub2.domain.com
 - app
 - lib
 - plugins
 - ...
```

It is how my hosting handle subdomains.
Folder `Cake` is a shared CakePHP core across all subdomains + main domain.

When SSL was installed, in cPanel was automatically added record `*.domain.com -> /public_html` that I can't change.

Everything works fine when I use http, but https redirect all my subdomains on main domain.
.htaccess in `/public_html` looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # http|https www to non-www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # redirect all subdomains
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,L,NS]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

All .htaccess files in subdomains are default CakePHP files with `RewriteBase /`

Did someone had similar situation and how did you solve it?
Please help as it really outside of my knowledge.

**Update #4**

`/public_html/sub1.domain.com/.htaccess` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^$ sub1.domain.com/app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule (.*) sub1.domain.com/app/webroot/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything looks ok, only
https://sub1.domain.com redirects to https://sub1.domain.com/sub1.domain.com
and all generated paths are includes /sub1.domain.com

How can I remove folder sub1.domain.com from URL and from links?

Should I update `Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));` on something else?
Still trying to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after 1 week (between other tasks) I solved this!

Here is my solution:

`/public_html/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # http|https www to non-www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # redirect all subdomains
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,L,NS]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`/public_html/sub1.domain.com/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/%{HTTP_HOST}
    RewriteRule ^%{HTTP_HOST}(.*)$ /$1

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^$ %{HTTP_HOST}/app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}/app/webroot/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`/public_html/sub1.domain.com/app/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

`/public_html/sub1.domain.com/app/webroot/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/index.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And finally the most important!

`/public_html/sub1.domain.com/app/webroot/index.php`

On the bottom: `$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();` changed to: `$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher('');`