# how to fix htaccess issues for subdomains and CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have Installed SSL certificate on server

The site is build on CakePHP 2.3 and public_html directory has a following structure:

```
/app
/lib
/plugins
/Cake
/newapp1
 - app
 - lib
 - plugins
 - ...
/newapp2
 - app
 - lib
 - plugins
 - ...
```

.htaccess in /public_html looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on   
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ htp://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(newapp1|newapp2)($|/) - [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

now when I am accessing site like: **`htps://mydomain.com/newapp`** then it works but whwn am accessing site with url **`htps://newapp.mydomain.com/`** then it opens my main cakephp site(htps://www.domain.com),

so how to fix that?

I tried **[Wildcard subdomains and CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819192/wildcard-subdomains-and-cakephp)** but its not working for me

**htps://newapp.mydomain.com/ points to main site(domain.com) but not to the directory newapp**

Comment: Why is the protocol lacking `t`s all over the place? Also please use proper example data and add version information (apache, mod_rewrite) if necessary, the rules you are showing here aren't capable of redirecting `https://newapp.mydomain.com/` to `https://www.domain.com`.

Comment: Also, you should use proper [vhost setup](http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/virtual-host/) to directly make webroot the document root. Then no htaccess chaining is required.

Comment: added htps because not able to add https, due to some validation here